# How Can I Convert From US-ASCII to UTF-8 with iconv?

Tags: utf-8, coldfusion, character-encoding, ascii, iconv

I'm attempting to convert multiple files in batch from US-ASCII to UTF-8. I've narrowed the problem down to the `iconv` comnand, which I appear to be using wrong, despite my best scouring of Stack Overflow. Any idea what's going wrong here?

Checking the encoding:

```
file -i accounting.cfm
accounting.cfm: text/html; charset=us-ascii
```

Attempt using `iconv` to convert:

```
iconv -f us-ascii -t utf-8 accounting.cfm > accounting.cfm.recode
```

Check the encoding on the resultant file:

```
file -i accounting.cfm.recode
accounting.cfm.recode: text/html; charset=us-ascii
```

It seems the resultant file is still encoded for the US-ASCII charset. When I save a single file through Sublime as UTF-8 (Save With Encoding), it show the charset as utf-8. I understand the US-ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, but when I bring up the US-ASCII encoded file in the browser, I get garbage characters (the dreaded question marks in diamonds if loaded in a browser). This is for a legacy ColdFusion site. When I bring up the file Saved With Encoding through Sublime, my foreign character set appears properly. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: An ASCII file is already an UTF-8 file because UTF-8 is backwards compatible. `file` prints the lowest common denominator; you just have to know what that means. Voting to close as unreproducible.

Comment: Saving as UTF-8 may add the BOM at the start of the file. These three bytes turn it into something else than US-ASCII, quite on purpose. It's not "garbled", you are just using an incorrect or misconfigured tool to inspect it.

Comment: Any suggestions on a better tool or use of the `file` command? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: If you still need help, see the Stack Overflow [`character-encoding` tag wiki](//stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info) for tips, at least on how to articulate a well-defined question.

Comment: Thanks, this is my first time delving into character encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out. ColdFusion does need the BOM to work correctly, unless you want to put a `<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8">` tag at the top of each and every CFM file you may have non-ASCII characters in. Reference:

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/930550
https://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/internationalization/internationalization_cfmx/internationalization_cfmx3.html

I'm a Sublime user, so I simply went to File -> Save With Encoding, UTF-8 with BOM, and it works without the tag. I then became quite happy that I spend most of my days in Python 3!